# Function overload using 'Const'

Tags: c++

There are 2 identical functions. One takes the argument with **const** keyword and another - without.

```
void A(const int* p);
void A(int* p);

int main()
{
    int x;
    A(&x);
    return 0;
}

void A(const int* p)
{
    cout << "2" << endl;
}

void A(int* p)
{
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
```

1. Is it function overloading?
2. Why function without **const** will be called it my case?

Comment: Yes it is function overloading. It would print `"1"` in your case. You'd have to declare `const int x = something;` to get `"2"`

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Because `x` is not declared as `const int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it function overloading?

Yes. The two functions have the same name but different parameters, so they are overloads.

> Why function without `const` will be called it my case?

Because `x` is not `const`. Try with a pointer to a `const int`, and you'll get the other overload:

```
const int y;
A(&y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is variation of the initial question : 
from Stroustrup's tour of c++

```
template<typename T>
class C {
    ...
    public:
    ...
    T& operator[](int i);
    const T& operator[](int i) const;
}
```

So as I understand it, the second method will target cases where the this-object is not intended to be modified.

I just wonder if the compiler is able to accurately guess that in every relevent case..